# Java GUI Dialog box hyperlink

Tags: java, swing, hyperlink, popup

Working on a project for my class. I am trying to add a clickable hyperlink to a pop dialog box (in a java swing gui) that the user can click to take them to a webpage. Currently, I've found pop up box hyperlinks that work by themselves, but nothing that I can use to attach to my dialog box. Is there a way to do such a thing? I'm using a binary search tree to execute the data, would it be possible to add it to the node, toString and the addNode methods to bring it up on the dialog box with a clickable hyperlink? The code I'm working with is below:

```
private void HydrogenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, (new1.theTree.findNode(1)
        + 
JPanel p = new JPanel();

JLabel link = new JLabel("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"+"Hydrogen");
link.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
link.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() 
   {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
    {
        if (e.getClickCount() > 0) 
        {
            if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) 
            {
                  Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
                  try 
                  {
                      String element = "Hydrogen";
                      URI uri = new URI("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"+element);
                      desktop.browse(uri);
                  } 
                  catch (IOException ex) 
                  {
                      ex.printStackTrace();
                  } 
                  catch (URISyntaxException ex) 
                  {
                      ex.printStackTrace();
                  }
            }
        }
    }
  });
```

p.add(link);
   getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, p);));

It's not functioning and I'm at a loss to get it to work. I'm open to any ideas.
Thanks.

Comment: The Object parameter to JOptionPane.showMesageDialog(Component, Object) can take a component which will be displayed on the dialog.  Add everything you want to show to a component and pass this reference to JOptionPane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the results of `new1.theTree.findNode(1)` in a `JLabel`

Add this label and your hyperlink label to the same `JPanel`, laid out however you want

Pass the reference to this panel to the `JOptionPane` via its `Object` parameter, `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Component, Object)`

Comment: Ok, now I have it able to print all the information. Just need to figure out how to make it clickable.

Comment: Managed to get all the information to print and now I need to figure out why the \n doesn't help format the string it prints.

Comment: Easier to make a series of `JLabel`s and layout them out on separate `JPanel`, but that's me.  You can also use `<html>`...